# Why does the form validation fail in this django formset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have been trying to make a django formset for giving feedback for assignments in a rubric style, where a form is generated for each criteria in an assignment, with the submissionID being automatically assigned, and the user selects what level the student has met a criteria to, and gives a comment about the criteria. Example:
[image: form example]

The problem I'm facing is that submitting the form does not do anything and just seems to refresh the current page, and I've tried everything I can think of to solve the problem, but the only thing I've managed to find out is where it is going wrong, which is at the line `if form.is_valid()`, which is returning false as it seems to be getting no forms passed to it for some reason.

The expected result of the code is that when a post request is sent, it loops through the submitted forms, sets the submissionID, and saves the forms. So far I have tried doing some debugging by printing variables at different points of the code but mainly the line before it fails.

Prints tried:

formset:
`

(Hidden field TOTAL_FORMS) This field is required.

(Hidden field INITIAL_FORMS) This field is required.

`

Number of forms in the formset: 0
Expected number of forms: 3

request.POST:
`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['KNTfj5LojMxZAxsYA6T0yuJa9SKKLBzf8F7qTs93vKYbgyVHqG20H1knyiTiuFZs'], 'criteriaLevelID': ['1', '6', '12'], 'comment': ['1', '2', '3']}>`

Edit:
I've compared this POST data to a similar form and the formatting seems to be the issue.

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['BltL9PLJ8x88AmFbIwhu1sgtGbiWeqBcKMrttgH3fPZ4jH5WWtxfcz6BhxF2Rtz9'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['3'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'form-0-assignmentID': ['11'], 'form-0-criteriaDescription': ['Criteria 1'], 'form-0-criteriaTotalMark': ['1'], 'form-0-id': [''], 'form-1-assignmentID': ['11'], 'form-1-criteriaDescription': ['Criteria 2'], 'form-1-criteriaTotalMark': ['2'], 'form-1-id': [''], 'form-2-assignmentID': ['11'], 'form-2-criteriaDescription': ['Criteria 3'], 'form-2-criteriaTotalMark': ['3'], 'form-2-id': ['']}>
```

You can see here that the data is being seperated by form, compared to the broken example where the dict values are being lumped by type. What causes this and how can I fix it?

formset.errors/form.errors:
just prints `[]`

As you can see the POST request contains the correct information, and I have also tried manually inputting the submissionID, which also prints correctly from the POST request data, but results in the same outcome as the forms themselves are still not being passed in for whatever reason.

views.py

```
def feedbackCreateView(request, pk):
    submission = Submission.objects.get(id=pk)
    assignment = submission.assignmentID
    criteria = Criteria.objects.filter(assignmentID=assignment.id)
    feedbackFormset = modelformset_factory(
        Feedback,
        form=FeedbackForm,
        extra=len(criteria),
        max_num=len(criteria),
    )

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = feedbackFormset(request.POST)
        print("Formset: ", formset)
        print("Number of forms in the formset: ", formset.total_form_count())
        print("Expected number of forms: ", len(criteria))
        print("Request.POST: ",request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                print("INSTANCE: " + instance)
                instance.submissionID = submission
                instance.save()
            return redirect('/')
        
        else:
            print("no Forms")
            for form in formset:
                print("No errors")
                if form.errors:
                    print(form.errors)
```

models.py

```
#Feedback
class Feedback(models.Model):
    submissionID = models.ForeignKey(Submission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    criteriaLevelID = models.ForeignKey(CriteriaLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

forms.py

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ['submissionID','criteriaLevelID', 'comment']
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated as I am at my wits end here and been working on this one problem for over a week now.